# AVAssetWriter error -12743 appending HDR Metadata

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-video, cvpixelbuffer, core-media

It seems AVAssetWriter is rejecting CVPixelBuffers with error -12743 when appending `NSData` for `kCVImageBufferAmbientViewingEnvironmentKey` for HDR videos.
Here is my code:

```
 var ambientViewingEnvironment:CMFormatDescription.Extensions.Value?
var ambientViewingEnvironmentData:NSData?
 ambientViewingEnvironment = sampleBuffer.formatDescription?.extensions[.ambientViewingEnvironment]
 let plist = ambientViewingEnvironment?.propertyListRepresentation
   ambientViewingEnvironmentData = plist as? NSData
```

And then attaching this data,

```
CVBufferSetAttachment(dstPixelBuffer, kCVImageBufferAmbientViewingEnvironmentKey,
 ambientViewingEnvironmentData! as CFData, .shouldPropagate)
```

No matter what I do, including copying the attachment from sourcePixelBuffer to destinationPixelBuffer as it is, the error remains!

```
  var attachmentMode:CVAttachmentMode = .shouldPropagate
  let attachment = CVBufferCopyAttachment(sourcePixelBuffer!, kCVImageBufferAmbientViewingEnvironmentKey, &attachmentMode)
  NSLog("Attachment \(attachment!), mode \(attachmentMode)")
  CVBufferSetAttachment(dstPixelBuffer, kCVImageBufferAmbientViewingEnvironmentKey, attachment!, attachmentMode)
```

I need to know if there is anything wrong in the way metadata is copied.

Comment: `-12743` is `kCMSampleBufferError_InvalidMediaFormat`. Do you have an examples of valid HDR data to compare yours against?